# Total of items in column where another column equals a value

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs, sumproduct

I have the following structure

```
Column1 Column2
Foo     100
Baa     200
```

How can I have a value that is the sum of all column2 values where its column1 value is equal to Foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a lot of solutions for this like:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A; "Foo"; B1:B)

=SUMIFS(B1:B; A1:A; "Foo")

=INDEX(SUM((A1:A="foo")*B1:B))

=SUM(FILTER(B1:B; A1:A="Foo"))

=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B*(A1:A="Foo"))

=QUERY(A1:B; "select sum(B) where A = 'Foo'")
```

Comment: Another one `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A="Foo")*(B2:B))`

Comment: thx so much, I used **=SUMIF(A1:A; "Foo"; B1:B)**, what does the syntax **A1:A** mean, and how can I make the text value soft match if it contains "Foo" in the whole cell, ie A1 = "Foo thing"

Comment: @FutuToad it varies on which solution you go for, but in your sumif case it would be adding an asterisk `*` after foo like: `=SUMIF(A1:A, "foo*", B1:B)`

Comment: i see many many thx

Comment: @player0 does the foo* match both sides?

Comment: @FutuToad nope, it would be `=SUMIF(A1:A, "*foo*", B1:B)`

Comment: ah cool many many thx

Comment: I tried this to add values in P together if **O** is not **0 %**, **=SUMIF(O56:O, NOT("0 %*"), P56:P)** but my Sum is always outputting 0

Comment: No luck either with **=SUMIF(O56:O, REGEXMATCH("/^[0 %]/"), P56:P)**

Comment: @FutuToad try: `=SUM(FILTER(P56:P; O56:O<>0%))` if not, share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: interesting, **=SUM(FILTER(P56:P, O56:O<>"0 %"))** also works

Comment: actually, no luck, cause this also matches
**=SUM(FILTER(P56:P, O56:O<>"0.2%"))**

Comment: here is the  sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Da8rvybw53-B2zUWW9O0dV7vfNKOCLlcxaXHeJNE53s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @FutuToad see green cells: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XzC_Tqdvny9fHyURCtd48G-ElJDoroNU5Sm3kqKVGLE/edit#gid=0

Comment: thx again, but wow, that got complex quick, shame its hard to just match a string exactly, all this extracting and multiplying is overcomplex, shame not an easier way to do this in sheets